# Bitrix D7 API: аналог OnSaleComponentOrderOneStepFinal

Tags: битрикс

Какой аналог события OnSaleComponentOrderOneStepFinal в  D7 API?

Comment: К сожалению как всегда по d7 очень скудная  [дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/event_sale_order_ajax.php) надо смотреть по ответам. Так сказать сложно что будет аналогом не зная вашей задачи.

Comment: @NikolajSarry задача простая - перехватить Order ID созданного заказа и отдать к примеру в систему ecommerce аналитики. В старой версии событие можно было поймать во время перенаправления на страницу подтверждения заказа (thank you page). Тут не вижу ничего подобного.

Answer (score 0):

Для перехватита данных заказа используйте смотря в каком методе есть нужные возвращаемые данные `OnSaleComponentOrderCreated` или `OnSaleComponentOrderUserResult`. Судя по Вашей задаче и описанию методов Вам больше подходит первый.

Comment: OnSaleComponentOrderCreated не будет вызываться на странице благодарения. Смотрите сами https://imgur.com/a/Os5Nh. Похоже, что Битрикс просто "отозвал" данное событие, не предоставив альтернативу в новой версии API.

Answer (score 0):

OnSaleOrderSaved делает эту работу. Конфуз был вызван тем, что по какой-то причине хук на данное событие не дает вывода в консоль браузера, однако для лога можно использовать file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно отнаследовать функцию saveOrder в самом компоненте sale.order.ajax и вызвать из нее родительскую функцию. Прежде всего, это удобно, если компонент у вас уже скопирован и класс отнаследован.

```
protected function saveOrder($saveToSession = false)
{
    // код до создания заказа
    parent::saveOrder($saveToSession);
    // код после создания заказа
}
```

[Кастомизация компонента заказа](http://estrin.pw/bitrix-d7-snippets/s/sale-order-ajax-customization/)